# Oracle Database won't output in my PHP table

Tags: php, oracle

I'm trying to output the data from a specific table within my Oracle SQL Developer database using a PHP form. I had some experience with this concept in the past using MySQL but I'm struggling to understand the differences between integrating it using Oracle specific syntax now.

My code is ideally laid out but when I run the code I get an error regarding the OCI_FETCH_ARRAY parameters, which I'm unsure on how to solve.

**My Code**

```
<?php
include("../connection.php");

error_reporting(E_ALL);

$sql = 'SELECT * FROM ALGORITHM';
$stid = oci_parse($conn, $sql);

echo "<table border='1'>";
echo "<tr> <th>ID</th> <th>Name</th> <th>Description<th> </tr>";

while($row= oci_fetch_array($stid, $sql))
{
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>" . $row ['Algorithm_ID'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row ['Algorithm_Name'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row ['Algorithm_Role'] . "</td>";
echo "</tr>";
}

echo "</table>";

oci_free_statement($stid);
oci_close($conn);

?>
```

**The Error I keep getting**

> Warning: oci_fetch_array() expects parameter 2 to be integer, string
>   given in
>   /studenthome.hallam.shu.ac.uk/STUDENTHOME8/1/b5040831/public_html/ADM/bin/php/entities/database.php
>   on line 12

I get that it's asking for an integer, but why? In the MySQL concept you simply outline the connection string it was never an issue.

Can anyone help ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Calling `oci_fetch_array()` ( from http://php.net/manual/en/function.oci-fetch-array.php) should be called like

```
while($row= oci_fetch_array($stid))
```

The second parameter is the mode - i.e. `OCI_ASSOC`.

**Update**: when using `oci_parse()`, this doesn't actually execute the parsed statement, you need to do...

```
oci_execute($stid);
```

So your code would be something like...

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM ALGORITHM';
$stid = oci_parse($conn, $sql);
oci_execute($stid);
echo "<table border='1'>";
echo "<tr> <th>ID</th> <th>Name</th> <th>Description<th> </tr>";

while($row= oci_fetch_array($stid, OCI_ASSOC))
```

(Look at http://php.net/manual/en/function.oci-parse.php for code examples)

Comment: I've tried changing it to `while($row = oci_fetch_array($stid, OCI_ASSOC))` but i now get an error telling me _ORA-24374: define not done before fetch or execute and fetch in_

Comment: Added to answer about calling `oci_execute($stid);` after parse.

Comment: Some progress has been made, however now I am receiving Undefined Index errors for Algorithm_ID, Algorithm_Name and Algorithm_Role which repeats 3 times.

Comment: OK, try adding a `print_r($row);` just at the start of the while loop, see what data your getting.

Comment: I added it above the while loop, but the code doesn't recognise the variable.

Comment: Add it IN the loop

Comment: Oops, sorry my bad. Thank you though, I reckon I solved the issue. I was calling to the variables but because of the it's case sensitivity it wasn't recognising them. It should have been `['ALGORITHM_ID']` instead of `['Algorithm_ID']`

Comment: It's OK, I know Oracle isn't case sensitive about column names, but arrays are.